# How do I read 0s and 1s from text input file and perform bit manipulation (shifting)

Tags: c, file-io, bit-manipulation

I have a text file input which has two columns with the first column having a binary number and the second column has the string width (which will be used when outputting data). I need to perform bit manipulation after reading the binary input.

I'm reading the input file using the below code and declared `input` as `unsigned int`.

```
while ((fscanf(fp,"%s %d", input, &count) != EOF))
```

After taking the input when I'm trying to perform bit manipulations I'm getting a "invalid operands to binary" error message. So I'm doing any declaration wrong or do I need to convert the binary to decimal to perform bit manipulations? I need to send output to a file as a bit sequence after manipulation.

Comment: `I need to perform bit manipulation after reading the binary input. ` so do I.

Comment: You say the second column in the text file is a string, but you read it as an integer. Also, attempting to read a binary number from a text file as an integer will not give you the correct value.

Comment: Also, type of variable used should match `fscanf` format specifiers. So in your case using "%s" with an `unsigned int` variable would result in undefined behavior

Comment: I should clarify - I read that as a integer since that specifies the width of the output binary string

Comment: Then you have the problem that you attempt to read the binary value as a string, but you pass an `unsigned int` variable to the function. That will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `fscanf` wil interpret that variable as a pointer to a string.

Comment: How do you advise I should be reading the binary value especially so that I can perform bit manipulation later in the program? Am I better of using fread?

Comment: reading to a character buffer (make sure it is large enough if it is preallocated before the `fscanf` call, or using "%ms" as format specifier), then using [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) using the `base` argument set to 2 would be one way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you added an input file example, but you first need to get the input correct. I suggest you first try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{       
        FILE    *fp;
        char    input[80];
        int     count;
        int     bin;

        fp = fopen("infile.txt", "r");
        while ((fscanf(fp,"%s %d", input, &count) != EOF)) {
                bin = strtol(input, NULL, 2);
                printf("input: %s, count %d, bin %d\n", input, count, bin);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

on an input file named "infile.txt" looking something like this:

```
0011101 10
1001011 20
0101011 30
1001010 40
```

This would give following output:

```
input: 0011101, count 10, bin 29
input: 1001011, count 20, bin 75
input: 0101011, count 30, bin 43
input: 1001010, count 40, bin 74
```

So if I'm not on the right track, let me know!

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact code I had from before but the function strtol was recommended by another user. Do you know if there is a similar function to convert from decimal back to binary?

Comment: Do you mean convert to a binary **string**? Your search engine can find lots of such converters. Just make sure you reserve enough space for the receiving buffer, and be aware that if your sprintf() can do the trick, it might not be portable.